# Unable to change WebView useragent Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview, user-agent

I am trying to WebView useragent. I have found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8432) that it should be change like that:

```
 webView.setUserAgentString("Mozilla / 5.0(Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build / JRO03C) AppleWebKit / 535.19(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/ 535.19");
```

But in my Xamarin forms app no setUserAgentString is found:

```
'WebView' does not contain a definition for 'setUserAgentString'
```

What should I do?

Comment: the link you posted contains a lengthy discussion of different workarounds

Comment: Is the project working on a xamarin android framework or xamarin forms?

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms

Comment: You can still use my code to set the user agent string for the android implementation of the same then implement the same separately for the iOS

Comment: But WebView is created in shared project. I am not sure how I could divide that? Check for platform on which app is running? Could you post an answer if you know it?

Comment: Unless the webview is in the common file Main.cs?

Comment: No it is declared at the top of the class like: using WebView = Xamarin.Forms.WebView;

Comment: Okay let me try and  see if there is a property we can use.

Comment: There is a solution on this page below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571751/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-in-webview-of-xamarin-forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252851/discussion-between-vytaute-and-dong-li).